# Do corporate events happen intraday?

Tags: equities, dividends, intraday, corporate-actions, split

Does any corporate event that affects the stock price/shares outstanding happen during the trading session in vanilla US Common stocks or predominantly at night ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the events that affect shares outstanding happen overnight.

Comment: I would assume same for price ?

Comment: Right, everything like splits/reverse splits happen overnight.

Comment: Not true: some events which affect price can happen intraday. For example: spin-off and merger announcements can occur during the trading day.

Comment: @kurtosis The announcement may happen intraday, but the actual event will happen overnight.

Comment: @LazyCat: OP asked about effects on price. Prices will respond immediately or, if the stock is halted, as soon as the re-opening auction is held for that stock.

Comment: @kurtosis I think you misinterpret the question

Comment: OP asked about events which "affect the stock price/shares outstanding." I agree that the corporate actions take place after hours; however, the announcement affects the price. OP even asks (above) about price.